# I cannot send a part of data from chrome extension to Spreadsheet via GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

I want to send some data from chrome extension to Spreadsheet via GAS, but only "last" is dropped, although "Title" and "URL" is sent successfully.

Hence, could you kindly check the code?

```
const gasUrl = "here is my spreadsheet GAS url";

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
  title = tabs[0].title;
  url = tabs[0].url;
  last = url.slice(-8); // I want to send url's last 8 letters.
  console.log(`Title: ${title}`);
  console.log(`URL: ${url}`);
  console.log(`Last: ${last}`); // I can see "last" is worked as intend here.
});

$(function() {
  $('#doit').on('click', function() {
    post2GAS(title, url, last);
  });
});

function post2GAS(title, url, last){
  const data = {
    title: title,
    url: url,
    last: last
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: gasUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .done(function (data) {
      console.log("success"); // I can see success on console.
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("failed");
      console.log("XMLHttpRequest : " + jqXHR.status);
      console.log("textStatus : " + textStatus);
      console.log("errorThrown : " + errorThrown);
    })
    .always((data) => {
      console.log("finished"); // I can see finished on console.
    });
}
```

Seems GAS cannot catch "last" param correctly, but I cannot find specific reason.

Here is GAS code.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var params = JSON.parse(e.postData.getDataAsString());
  var title  = params.title;
  var url    = params.url;
  var last = params.last;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet ID').getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  sheet.appendRow([title, url, last]);

  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  output.setContent(JSON.stringify( { sucsess: true }));
  return output;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you overwrite `last` somewhere else? What happens if you rename it? Do you see it in devtools network inspector for the request details? Try inspecting the request in Fiddler (or Charles) proxy tool.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail by show us the GAS's response, or add more log on the GAS code and see what happen?

Comment: Thank you guys, here is GAS's log.

`
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined at doPost(code:3:29)
`

Seems strange cuz Spreadsheet got url and title. Also, even I rename, issue is remained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, I have not deploy new GAS.
And when I deployed, it's solved.

Hence, I'm close this ticket here.